# formula in excel if the date

Tags: date, formula

I LOOKING FOR formula in excel if the date = OR UNDER 16 OF MONTHE in (A8) THEN PRICE IS 17.5$
IF NOTE THE PRICE 8.75$
any ideas?

If the date of the invoice between 01-16 of monthe the charge will be 17.5$
if it is between 16-end of month the cgarge is 8.75$

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

[image]

Formula to save typing:

```
=IF(DAY(A2)<=16,17.5,8.75)
```

You could bring the amounts out to separate cells for easier editing when they change:
[image]